# Simple search by value?

Tags: database, redis

I would like to store some information as follows (note, I'm not wedded to this data structure at all, but this shows you the underlying **information** I want to store):

```
{ user_id: 12345, page_id: 2, country: 'DE' }
```

In these records, user_id is a unique field, but the page_id is not.

I would like to translate this into a Redis data structure, and I would like to be able to run efficient searches as follows:

- For user_id 12345, find the related country.
- For page_id 2, find all related user_ids and their countries.

Is it actually possible to do this in Redis? If so, what data structures should I use, and how should I avoid the possibility of duplicating records when I insert them?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It sounds like you need two key types: a HASH key to store your user's data, and a LIST for each page that contains a list of related users.  Below is an example of how this could work.

Load Data:

```
> RPUSH page:2:users 12345
> HMSET user:12345 country DE key2 value2
```

Pull Data:

```
# All users for page 2
> LRANGE page:2:users 0 -1

# All users for page 2 and their countries
> SORT page:2:users By nosort GET # GET user:*->country GET user:*->key2
```

Remove User From Page:

```
> LREM page:2:users 0 12345
```

Repeat GETs in the SORT to retrieve additional values for the user.

I hope this helps, let me know if there's anything you'd like clarified or if you need further assistance.  I also recommend reading the commands list and documentation available at the [redis web site](http://redis.io), especially concerning the SORT operation.

Comment: Thanks - actually I ended using a HASH and a SET, rather than a LIST - but good answer!

Answer (score 1):

Since user_id is unique and so does country, keep them in a simple key-value pair. Quering for a user is O(1) in such a case... Then, keep some Redis [sets](http://redis.io/commands#set), with key the page_id and members all the user_ids..

Comment: Thanks. My concern about this is: what if you insert a new user into the key-value, then *before* you can add the set entry, the database goes down? When it comes back up, you'll be left with nasty half-entered bits of information.

Comment: In such a case, you have two options: either keep some kind of state in your client code, in other words, examine the result that redis returns after every operation and behave accordingly in failure cases, or use http://redis.io/commands#transactions;

Comment: actually, multi/exec seems to be the way to go